# Angular 4: two diffrent values of a Radio button value in component

Tags: angular

I am not sure why I am getting two different values in my component. When I click first time on Shift A, then I am getting value as 2, then when I click again, I am getting 1. Any ideas why it is so...

Also I want to select Shift A when the page loads. Thanks in advance for your help!!

**lineside-monitor.component.html:**

```
<div class="box">
            <div class="row moveright">
                <div>
                    Shift A <input type="radio" name="shiftRadioGroup" [value]="1" [(ngModel)]="shiftRadioBtn" (click)="popuplateBySearchFilter(1)">
                </div>
                <div class="notsotall">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </div>
                <div>
                    Shift B <input type="radio" name="shiftRadioGroup" [value]="2" [(ngModel)]="shiftRadioBtn"         (click)="popuplateBySearchFilter(2)">
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

**lineside-monitor.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-lineside-monitor',
  templateUrl: './lineside-monitor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lineside-monitor.component.css']
})
export class LinesideMonitorComponent implements OnInit {
public shiftRadioBtn: string;// = "1";
ngOnInit() {
      this.shiftRadioBtn="1";
}

popuplateBySearchFilter(modelId: number) {
    alert(this.shiftRadioBtn);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are considering those radio button value as `string`, use `value` attribute instead of `[value]`(attribute binding). Otherwise you have to set initial `shiftRadioBtn` value to be `1`(number) rather than `"1"`(string)

Also for getting correct value to be printed on change of radio button selection, use `change` event instead of `click` event.

```
<div>
    Shift A 
    <input type="radio" name="shiftRadioGroup" value="1" 
      [(ngModel)]="shiftRadioBtn" (change)="popuplateBySearchFilter(1)" />
</div>
<div class="notsotall">
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
</div>
<div>
    Shift B 
    <input type="radio" name="shiftRadioGroup" value="2" 
     [(ngModel)]="shiftRadioBtn" (change)="popuplateBySearchFilter(2)" />
</div>
```

Running [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aa8n65?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: sweet!!. How you are create a stackblitz so quick, I have to learn. I have a github project, and want to create stackblitz from that: https://github.com/SudhirSahoo/IQS                 Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SK. its way simpler to use for quick code sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Why? because you're binding the model in two-way mode to the radio button, so whenever you click the radio button automatically it changes the `shiftRadioBtn` model base on the `[value]` in the radio button.